# PHP connection to Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I have the following PHP code to connect to the Oracle database

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<h1> Oracle connectivity </h1>
<p>
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'Password', 'localhost:1521/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
?>
</p>
</html>
```

I am getting the error

```
Call to undefined function oci_connect()
```

I have uncommented `extension=php_oci8.php` statement as well.

I am using Xampp. I have started apache and placed the file in the `C:\\xampp\htdocs` folder as needed. The error still persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function oci\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478387/call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect)

Comment: I have tried this. I tried installing the 32 bit version as mentioned, but it still gives me the same error.