# PHP Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I have PHP 7.3.0 installed on a Windows 2012 Server using fast-cgi. 
I have a test file trying to connect to an Oracle database. I get the error "Call to undefined function oci_connect()"

In my php.ini file I have enabled extension=php_oci8_12c.dll and  (The Oracle db I need to connect to is 12c).

I need help to figure out exactly what do I need to download and install on the server to get OCI to work. I have tried so many different things, I have lost track of what I have tried to get it to work. It's driving me nuts. I anot having much luck finding good step-by-step documentation online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function oci\_connect, php\_oci8\_11g.dll , windows 10, php5.6.24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843326/call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect-php-oci8-11g-dll-windows-10-php5-6-24)

Comment: This question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947809/how-to-connect-an-oracle-database-from-php