# Configuring Oracle connection in PHP 4.4.8

Tags: php, php4

Issue is regarding PHP 4.4.8, having trouble in configuring oracle connection (server is IIS8). I tried using php data objects(PDO) it didn't work. I also tried using extension php_oci8.dll

```
function getConnection()
{
    return $this->createConnection();
}

function createConnection()
{
    return oci_new_connect ("***", "****", "****");
}
```

getting error: "Call to undefined function: oci_new_connect()"

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478387/call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect. PDO is supported in PHP5 for linux users and under windows i think it is PHP version 5.3 and later.

Comment: For information, support for PHP 4 has been discontinued by its developers since January 2008, and PDO is not available for this version. I suggest you to upgrade to *at least* PHP 5.3 so you can have access to the OCI8 extension.

Comment: wow, a 10 years old PHP version. Never touch a running system is not all the time the way to go ;)

Answer (score 0):

review PHP.ini and see if the dll is enabled or even present in the filesystem.