# How to connect from php to Oracle DB 12c?

Tags: php, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-call-interface

I am using XAMPP v3.2.2 and I am trying to connect from PHP to Oracle database 12c.

I have already commented out the extension `php_oci8_12c.dll` in php.ini, restarted Apache, and installed Oracle instantclient_12_2 32bit.

However, I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478387/call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect

Comment: Yes, of course !!

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions for XAMPP v3.2.2 and Oracle database 12c config.

1. Download instantclient_12_2 and unzip to c:\instantclient_12_2 (make sure your xamp and instantclient both are same architechture x86 or 64-bit)
2. setup ENVIRONMENT PATH for c:\instantclient_12_2 before any oracle directory. Restart PC
3. download oci8 dll from http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.0.6/windows
4. select 5.5 Thread Safe (TS) x64 from above link
5. unzip and copy all files to c:/xampp/php/ext directory
6. open php.ini remove (;) for extension=php_oci8.dll, extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  and save it
7. restart apache
8. look phpinfo and search for oci8 module if found and enabled then ok.
9. test with php oracle connection script .