# Unable to load OCI8 Library with PHP 8 on windows 10 machine

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I am trying to load the oci8_12c library in php 8 on windows 10 machine .

The module is loaded but it shows the following error :

[image]

I did download the oracle instant client ( 12.1.0 ) and added it to the PATH .

Please help .

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677810/2310830

Comment: Of Course , I just tried it again with the same result !

Comment: Please post the error message as text rather than as a screen capture.

Comment: Try a newer Oracle Instant Client version (it should still work with oci8_12c).  Make sure you have the correct VS redistributable noted in the download page instructions.  Reboot/restart to make sure PATH is picked up. Set the system path.

Comment: Are both PHP and Oracle client 64-bit (or both 32-bit)?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for replies .

The problem was with the oci8 library .

for anyone coming here you should be aware of your php version while picking the dll library from the link below .

[PECL Page for oci8](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/)