# How to fix error "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()" in wamp server?

Tags: php, oracle, error-handling

I have uncommented the following two lines in my php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll
```

Code:

```
public static function getAllNames(){
    $dbUser = "xxx";
    $dbPass = "xxxx";
    $dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxx)))";
    $conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
    $sql = oci_parse($conn,"Select FNAME, LNAME from PERSONA  WHERE STATUS = 'A' ORDER BY FNAME");
    return $sql;
    }
```

I'm not able to get rid of the error. I have seen a couple of questions similar to mine, but most of them were using apache server and couldn't really solve my problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did you download **Oracle Instant Client** ?

Comment: Yes. i have downloaded that

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478387/call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect, maybe because you install  Oracle Instant Client 64bit. try to install the 32bit version

Comment: Okay. Do i need to install the file in a specific directory?

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/40080784/8010101 maybe help

Comment: As the instructions say you have to add the path where the Instant Client is to your path. It doesn't really matter where it is installed but its location MUST be in the system path.

Comment: Okay tried that. Didn't work :(

Comment: what is the PATH you add ??

Comment: C:\oci8-2.0.12\instantclient_19_8
C:\oci8-2.0.12\instantclient_11_2

Added both versions, separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue but with `mysqli_connect()`

I removed and did autoremove the webserver and php and reinstalled them again, and it worked.