# WAMP server stopped working due to Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle11g

So far I am using WAMP server with oracle successfully past one year,but unfortunately it stopped working and displaying an error like this **Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()**. I verified all DLL files and connection I dint do any modification for past one year and verified all related link **[Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635881/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect)**.How can I fix this error.kind give some solution.

I have refer and verified lots of reference links. But everything is perfect. Past 1 year it was working perfectly, but today morning it will not work and shown the above error here, How can I solve this?

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` say the extension is loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle 11.1.0.7 and WAMP oci\_connect failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099158/oracle-11-1-0-7-and-wamp-oci-connect-failure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be dll was crashed. Can you update the required dlls?

Otherwise reinstall the Oracle?

It will work..

Answer (score 0):

Please check your PHP version first. it must be not latest one also your wamp server is around 2.2.

Please add require oracle extension from [here](http://originaldll.com/file/php_oci8_11g.dll/32011.html).

Add

> php_oci8_11g.dll

In php.ini and enable extension.

Its working for me. Still have issue let me know.